# Is there a way we can have tag icons?

Tags: discussion

Just noticed that the [PHPStorm tag on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/phpstorm/info) has a nice little icon next to it.

Can we have that at some point ?

Comment: I asked this before graduation: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/q/233/146. We can take an other shot now.

Comment: @Marius yep I'm in. Let me know if I can do something to help.

Comment: I don't think it is up to us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag icons are sponsored (paid!), so I doubt that you can add icons just for fun.

#### Reference:

[What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

[The PHP tag needs a tag icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56391/the-php-tag-needs-a-tag-icon)